# Warning: call_user_func() [function.call-user-func]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback

Tags: php, scope, callback

```
class myClass {
    $myVariable = 'myCallback';
    
    function myFunction() {
        $body = false;
        $callback = $this->myVariable;
        
        function test($handle, $line) {
            global $body, $callback;
            
            if ($body) {
                call_user_func($callback, $line);
            }
            
            if ($line === "\r\n") {
                $body = true;
            }
            
            return strlen($line);
        }
        
        ...
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 'test');
        ...
    }
}

function myCallback($data) {
    print $data;
}

$myCls = new myClass();
$myCls->myFunction();
```

> Warning: call_user_func() [function.call-user-func]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback !

My `$callback` value is empty, how can I resolve this issue?

Restriction: `myCallback` function cannot be changed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the fun of it another one ... (not tested though).

```
class myClass
{
    protected $callback = 'myCallback';
    protected $body = false;

    public function myFunction()
    {
        ...
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, array($this, 'test'));
        ...
    }


    public function test($handle, $line)
    {
        if ($this->body) {
            call_user_func($this->callback, $line);
        }

        if ($line === "\r\n") {
            $body = true;
        }

        return strlen($line);
    }
}

function myCallback($data) {
    print $data;
}

$myCls = new myClass();
$myCls->myFunction();
```

Answer (score 10):

**Important:** This is only possible in PHP  >= 5.3. The OP does not use PHP 5.3 but I will leave the answer here in case someone has a similar problem and uses PHP 5.3.

---

`$callback` is not a global variable, it is local in the methods scope. From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):

> Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope. **Any such variables must be declared in the function header. Inheriting variables from the parent scope is not the same as using global variables.** Global variables exist in the global scope, which is the same no matter what function is executing. The parent scope of a closure is the function in which the closure was declared (not necessarily the function it was called from).

Make use of `use` (and assign the function to a variable):

```
$test = function($handle, $line) use ($callback, $body){

    if ($body) {
        call_user_func($callback, $line);
    }

    if ($line === "\r\n") {
        $body = true;
    }

    return strlen($line);
};
```

and later:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, $test);
```

Comment: You cannot define Closures without assigning them to a variable

Comment: @Gordon: Good point, you are right, at least when you want to use `use`, you have to assign it to a variable. I get a syntax error otherwise (or I am doing something stupid ;))

Comment: @Felix Closures and Lambdas are objects. That's why you have to assign them. They are supposed to be passed around. From docs: *Anonymous functions are currently implemented using the  Closure class.* - you should also note that they are only available since 5.3

Comment: Do you have a solution for PHP 5.2 ?

Comment: @Fabien: Make your test function a method in MyClass

Comment: @Fabien Bernede: Please see Gordon's answer.

Comment: @Fabien The Pre5.3 way to create lambdas ( [not closures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209327/is-it-possible-to-simulate-closures-in-php-5-2-x-not-using-globals) ) is to use `create_function`, but this is slow and kinda ugly and wont let you close over variables (e.g. no `use` keyword).

Answer (score 2):

With the exception of the missing keyword when declaring `$myVariable`, this should not throw an error at all, because inside the `test()` function `$body` is `NULL` unless you defined it in the global scope. In other words, your *myCallback* should never get called. Apparently, you did define `$body` in the global scope though and made it a great example of why using globals will lead to all sorts of unexpected behavior. If you would define `$callback` in the global scope to hold 'myCallback' it should work, but you dont want globals.

And do yourself a favor and get rid of the function in the method:

```
class myClass {

    protected $_myVariable = 'myCallback';

    public function myFunction()
    {
        // calling callback that calls callback (should make you think ;))
        // that would be your curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 'test');
        echo call_user_func_array(
            array($this, '_test'),
            array('body', 'foo', 'bar'));
    }

    protected function _test($body, $handle, $line)
    {
        if ($body) {
            call_user_func($this->_myVariable, $line);
        }
        if ($line === "\r\n") {
            $body = true;
        }
        return strlen($line);
    }
}
```

The `test()` function is now a method inside your class. This is much clearer and more maintainable than putting the code flow into some function inside a method. Note that I pass in `$body` as the first argument. I dont know how cURL accepts callbacks or what it passes to them. If you cannot make `$body` the first argument, make it a class member check for it's state with `$this->body` instead ([as now shown by Philippe below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360417/php-scope-callback/3360724#3360724))

Comment: Ha, I should have had a look at that ;) Anyway, I tried it too and it works indeed +1 (deleted my other nonsense comments)