# How can I use PHP closure function like function() use() on PHP 5.2 version?

Tags: php, function

How can I use PHP closure function like function() use() on PHP 5.2 version as it has no support for anonymous functions?

Currently my code is something like below

```
$this->init(function() use($taxonomy_name, $plural, $post_type_name, $options)
{
   // Override defaults with user provided options

    $options = array_merge(
       array(
          "hierarchical" => false,
          "label" => $taxonomy_name,
          "singular_label" => $plural,
          "show_ui" => true,
          "query_var" => true,
          "rewrite" => array("slug" => strtolower($taxonomy_name))
        ), $options
      );

      // name of taxonomy, associated post type, options
      register_taxonomy(strtolower($taxonomy_name), $post_type_name, $options);
});
```

Comment: Just a note, use the code button (the `{}` button) on the toolbar to format code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to simulate closures in PHP 5.2.x not using globals?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209327/is-it-possible-to-simulate-closures-in-php-5-2-x-not-using-globals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Php supports anonymous functions since 5.3.0, read about it in [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

You could use `create_function` but you should avoid this (for example because of [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php#46326)) and it's practically the same as eval... One bad enclosure and you'll make your sources vulnerable. It's also evaluted on runtime, not on compilation time what can decrease performance and may cause fatal error in the middle of included file.

Rather declare that function somewhere, it'll be more effective.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are asking for the 'use' directive due to the early value bindings, right?
You could use 'create function' and insert there some static variables with the values you have at the creation time, for example

```
$code = '

static $taxonomy_name = "'.$taxonomy_name.'";
static $plural = "'.$plural.'";
static $post_type_name = "'.$post_type_name.'";
static $options = json_decode("'.json_encode($options).'");

$options = array_merge(
    array(
         "hierarchical" => false,
         "label" => $taxonomy_name,
         "singular_label" => $plural,
         "show_ui" => true,
         "query_var" => true,
         "rewrite" => array("slug" => strtolower($taxonomy_name))
    ),
    $options
);

// name of taxonomy, associated post type, options
register_taxonomy(strtolower($taxonomy_name), $post_type_name, $options);
            ';

$func = create_function('', $code);
```

Comment: I personally consider `create_function` (along with `eval`) one of features of php which "kills kittens". It's slower and less effective than creating the function somewhere in file + it's parsed on runtime not in compilation... I don't know... I just... Why would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should do:

```
$this->init(create_function('','
    $taxonomy_name = '.var_export($taxonomy_name,TRUE).'; 
    $plural = '.var_export($plural,TRUE).'; 
    $post_type_name = '.var_export($post_type_name,TRUE).'; 
    $options = '.var_export($options,TRUE).'; 

    $options = array_merge(
       array(
          "hierarchical" => false,
          "label" => $taxonomy_name,
          "singular_label" => $plural,
          "show_ui" => true,
          "query_var" => true,
          "rewrite" => array("slug" => strtolower($taxonomy_name))
        ), $options
      );

      // name of taxonomy, associated post type, options
      register_taxonomy(strtolower($taxonomy_name), $post_type_name, $options);
'));
```